# Trying to convert a String to DateTime but it throws exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to display date in format `17 May 2022` but when using DateFormat it is throwing the below Exception.

> Trying to read MMMM from 2022-05-16 21:39:39.333741 at position 0

[image]

```
return GroupedListView<dynamic, DateTime>(
  elements: messageList,
  groupBy: (element) => DateFormat.yMMMMd().parse(element['time']),
  groupSeparatorBuilder: (DateTime groupByvalue) {
    return Container(child: Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(groupByvalue)));
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, element) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(element['message']),
    );
  },
);
```

> {
> 'time': '2022-05-16 21:39:39.333741',
> 'message': "hello",
> 'messagetype': Messagetype.receiver
> },

above is a sample 'time' i used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your format date are wrong,

Try convert your date to new format

Example:

```
dateFormate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z").format(DateTime.parse("2022-05-16 21:39:39.333741"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parse first, then format the type `17 May 2022` later
like this :

```
final dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z").parse('2022-05-16 21:39:39.333741');

final dateTimeString = DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return GroupedListView<dynamic, DateTime>(
      elements: messageList,
      groupBy: (element) => DateFormat.yMMMMd().parse(DateTime.parse(element['time'])),
      groupSeparatorBuilder: (DateTime groupByvalue) {
        return Container(child: Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(groupByvalue)));
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, element) {
        return Container(
          child: Text(element['message']),
        );
      },
    );**
```